# Ruby on Rails Validation Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I've set up a small app that takes an email address and saves it, I've set up validation on the model (unique and valid email) and these both work.

I'm using the below code to try save the email, if it already exists or its not a valid format it needs to stop and set the error message

```
def create
    interest = KnownInterest.new( :email => params[:email] )
    if(interest.valid? and interest.save)
        flash[:notice] = "Thanks for showing interest, We'll be in touch with updates."
    else
        flash[:notice] = interest.errors.messages
    end     
    redirect_to action: "index"
end
```

this spits out ["Email not valid"], how do i get this to be a string (not what I think is an array, correct me if I'm wrong)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you just want the first message then `interest.errors.messages.first`. If you want them all then something like `interest.errors.full_messages.join(", ")` will group all the messages into one string.

However you might want to brush up on `ActiveRecord` validations and errors.
Here's a pretty good guide:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html

Read at least:

- Section 7: [Working With Validation Errors](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/activerecord_validations_callbacks.html#working-with-validation-errors)
- Section 8: [Displaying Validation Errors](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/activerecord_validations_callbacks.html#displaying-validation-errors-in-the-view)

Comment: That should actually be `interest.errors.full_messages.join(', ')` - note `full_messages` instead of `messages` (at least this is the case in Rails 3.2)

Answer (score 4):

`.messages` will return an array of all your errors. Even if its just one.

So to properly display them, do this in your view :

```
- for error in flash[:notice] do
  = error
```

Or if you prefer `html.erb` :

```
<%- for error in flash[:notice] do %>
    <%= error %>
<%- end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

This one work for me :

```
<html>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
        <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
      <% end %>
      <%= yield %>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
      <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

`interest.errors.messages.join(<any concatenating character>)` will create a string concatenating your array elements.

You can use a string - such as ", " , ": " or pretty much anything to concatenate.

Comment: @equipment.errors.messages.join(", ") => undefined method `join' for #<ActiveSupport::OrderedHash:0x007fbe12054650>